# SQL - UPDATE empty cells to 0 (double precision)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple question. I want to update empty cells to 0 in my PostgreSQL table. 
As always I used:

```
 UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn = 0 WHERE somecolumn = '';
```

Unfortunately I always get an error which says, that

> syntax in not valid for double precision.

Comment: which dbms are you using? and somecolumn datatype please

Comment: PostgresSQL. Datatype is double precision.

Comment: `UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn = 0 WHERE somecolumn IS NULL`

Comment: show table structure

Comment: `''` is a string not a number, which is why you are getting the error. Anyway, just out of curiosity: Is there any reason you use the approximate datatype `double precision` instead of the exact type `decimal`? It is rare for a database to contain inexact data types.

Comment: To add to Thorsten's comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/ explains why `double` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`somecolumn` datatype must be an integer so you should try,

```
UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn = 0 WHERE somecolumn IS NULL
```